# Bulk transfers ETH or token - gas price

Tags: airdrop

If I make a bulk transfer with multi sender apps or an array in a smart contract or airdrop apps - will this be one time the gas price only?

Comment: Depending on the number of recipients a contract could achieve that operation in a single transaction. If the number is quite large you would have to split into several transactions.

Comment: Let’s say I want to make 10 transactions

Comment: But will that cost me 10 x 1 transaction gas fee or is it cheaper?

Comment: It depends on the contract, there's a minimum 21000 gas per transaction, and a contract has to pay 9000 to transfer ethers to an existing account. Probably it would be cheaper than sending 10 transactions but it will be more than sending a single transfer.

Comment: So it has to pay 9000 for each transaction - so 90,000 in this case

Comment: It is an approximation, it is better to test with the deployed contracts to be sure.

Comment: The gas amounts you took from the white paper ?

Comment: Those values are from the Ethereum Yellow paper, I haven't checked if they are the latest ones.